# How to track URL and apps using Electron.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, browser, electron

I am making team management software with **electron js**. I want to track the **URL** and **apps** visited by the user of our app. Then it will go to our server and we will store it. But how to track the **URL** and **apps** visited by the user as Hubstaff does? I am using electron.js.

> URL Tracking

> App Tracking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use this library [active-win](https://www.npmjs.com/package/active-win) to track apps and url visited by the user, but there is one problem of this library it gives you the url of the active tab only in Mac OS:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I also need to track the active apps. It tracks the active apps. It gives the active window information.

Comment: I have tracked Apps using the package you told. But do you know any other package that can track Windows, macOS and Linux URLs?

Comment: For the moment I didn't find any way to do that in Windows, but If I found something I will share with you.

Answer (score 0):

> How I will get access to the chrome variable? – Ashikur Rahman Munna

The Chrome functions are part of the Chromium APIs which are accessible to Node-Webkit, Electron, and Chromium developers, when they include such library names in their *manifest.json*.

Here's the guide to one such library which is very popular and useful:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/

You included the **[Electron]** tag in your post so I assumed you knew all about such things.

Maybe you've only just started out in Electron... in which case I'd say that this job may be a bit too advanced for you right now.

Answer (score -1):

You can only achieve this with **network monitoring** but it’s a lot of data so you may want to filter out most of it.

Here's what I do when my browser users decide to enable "*network monitoring*", which is a useful feature for them to catch the URLs of streams etc.

```
var LogFile='';  // global variable

    
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){

 LogFile='<tr><td>'+details.requestId+'</td><td>'+details.method+'</td><td>'+details.frameId+'</td><td>'+details.type+'</td><td>'+details.url+'</td></tr>'+LogFile;

},{urls:['<all_urls>']},['blocking','requestHeaders']);
```

So I basically build a table of all activity which they can then view when they press [F1] as a table.

Needless to remind that in your **manifest.json** file you’ll have to include:

```
 "permissions": "webRequestBlocking", etc... etc...]
```

...to access such a function.

Comment: How I will get access to the chrome variable?

Answer (score -1):

URL changes can be easily tracked in Electron by use of the [webContents](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents) module.

The below code (as shown in the Electron API documentation) will list all the attributes of the webContents object.

```js
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 1500 })
win.loadURL('http://github.com')

const contents = win.webContents
console.log(contents)
```

[Instance events](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#instance-events) that will be of particular interest to you for URL tracking will be:

- [Event 'will-navigate'](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-will-navigate)
- [Event 'did-start-navigaion'](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-did-start-navigation)
- [Event 'will-redirect'](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-will-redirect)
- [Event 'did-redirect-navigation'](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-did-redirect-navigation)
- [Event 'did-navigate'](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-did-navigate)
- [Event 'did-frame-navigate'](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-did-frame-navigate)
- [Event 'did-navigate-in-page'](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-did-navigate-in-page)

---

Regarding the tracking of applications used, I do not believe Electron has the capacity to do this alone.

You may need the assistance of a C# add-in, pre-made (if you can find one) or custom coded by yourself.

Comment: I need low-level API to track URLs and Apps used by the user. This will only record the navigations inside the electron app.

Comment: Anything low level will require the use of C++ or C# . Excluding  Electron, tracking URLs require network monitoring.  Additionally, tracking the use of locally installed apps requires you to look at services or something equivalent.